# Expected Value Of $X^{2}$

Tags: probability

> Let $Y=X^2$ and $X\sim Bin(n,p)$ find E[Y]

I know that $E[X^2]=E[X]*E[X]$ only if the both are independent, but that is not the case as it the same random variable, how should I approach this?

Comment: Using the *definition* of E(X^2), perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: use the variance.

$V(X)=E(X^2)-[E(X)]^2$, so $E(X^2)=V(X)+[E(X)]^2$.